# Probability of event, How should I continue from here?

Tags: probability

Let $R>1$ be real number. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be probability measure  on probability space $$\Omega=\mathbb{N}\smallsetminus\{0\}=\{1,2,3,...\}$$  such that $$\mathbb{P}[ \{ n \} ] = C\cdot n^{-R}$$ for every $$n\in\Omega$$ and $C>0$ is constant. Define the event $A_m$ as a given number that is a multiple of $m$ $$A_m = \{ k\cdot m \  : \ k\in\mathbb{N}\smallsetminus\{0\} \} = \{m,2m,3m,...\}$$

calculate $P[A_m]$

My attempt:

I argue that $A_m$ is union of disjoint sets thus $$P[A_m]= \Sigma^{k=\infty}_{k=1}C\cdot(km)^{-R}$$ $$C\cdot m^{-R}\Sigma^{k=\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^{R}}$$

I dont know how should I procedd from here.

Comment: This geometric series is looks not familiar for me since the index is in the numerator itself and not in the power. how do I calculate this series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You are very close. Note that $C \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^R} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(\{k\})$

Comment: but the most right expression is the probablity of all the probablity space wich is equal to $1$ if I understood you correctly

Comment: am I right in my assumption?

Comment: @Sagigever yep that's right

Comment: Why is this equation is true? I would like if you can show me where it yield from.